# How to trigger an Api call when it's the scheduled time

Tags: api, go, microservices, twitter-api-v2

I'm building a simple platform to allow Twitter users to post to their Twitter accounts on a time schedule of their choosing. So for example someone might want to make a post to his/her Twitter account at exactly 12:00 am midnight, but the platform allows them to create the post by 4:00 pm and automatically post to their timeline when it's the scheduled time. I'm confused as to how to implement this since the Api endpoint responsible for this action has to be called manually for this event to take place, I thought of using cron jobs to run every minute and check for all the scheduled posts, call the endpoint if it's time to create the post, but I feel this is cumbersome and error-prone. Are there any more programmatic ways of implementing this, please?

Ps: I'm trying to do this in golang...

Comment: Your program could simply keep track of when the next request is and sleep() until then. Not really a better solution since you're creating a new daemon, but it avoids cron. You could also use `at` of course

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Pub/Consumer model with a message queue. It will make your solution more robust and distributed. I always try not to use sleep in any kind of distributed environment.

Your system will have 3 components: 
**Producer**: This will take care of scheduling and writing messages to a message queue. 
**Message Queue**: You can use RabbitMQ(with delayMessageExchange) or ActiveMQ(it has in-built scheduling). Your message queue will take care of the scheduling problem. Because the message will be delivered only after a specific time delay to the consumer. 
**Consumer**: The consumer will read data from the message queue and perform operations as the functionality

HLD will look like this:
[image]

You can use https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/streadway/amqp this package for RabbitMQ
and https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-stomp/stomp this package for ActiveMQ

Here is an simple example, I have used AWS ActiveMQ.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-stomp/stomp/v3"
    "os"
    "time"
)

const defaultPort = ":61613"

var serverAddr = flag.String("server", "b-50ad5529-0347-4308-af59-f6265d68d290-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61614", "STOMP server endpoint") 
var messageCount = flag.Int("count", 2, "Number of messages to send/receive")
var queueName = flag.String("queue", "/queue/client_test", "Destination queue")
var helpFlag = flag.Bool("help", false, "Print help text")
var stop = make(chan bool)

// these are the default options that work with RabbitMQ
var options []func(*stomp.Conn) error = []func(*stomp.Conn) error{
    stomp.ConnOpt.Login("activemquser", "activemqpassword"),
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if *helpFlag {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage of %s\n", os.Args[0])
        flag.PrintDefaults()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    subscribed := make(chan bool)
    go recvMessages(subscribed)

    // wait until we know the receiver has subscribed
    <-subscribed

    go sendMessages()

    <-stop
    <-stop

}

func sendMessages() {
    defer func() {
        stop <- true
    }()

    netConn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", *serverAddr, &tls.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        println("cannot connect to server", err.Error())
    }

    conn, err := stomp.Connect(netConn, options...)
    if err != nil {
        println("cannot connect to server", err.Error())
    }

    for i := 1; i <= *messageCount; i++ {
        text := fmt.Sprintf("Message #%d", i)
        fmt.Println("sending message ", text, " ", time.Now())
        // scheduling a message with 15 seconds delay
        err = conn.Send(*queueName, "text/plain",
            []byte(text), stomp.SendOpt.Header("AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY", "15000"))
        if err != nil {
            println("failed to send to server", err)
            return
        }
        // schedule each message after 3 secs
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    }
    println("sender finished")
}

func recvMessages(subscribed chan bool) {
    defer func() {
        stop <- true
    }()

    netConn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", *serverAddr, &tls.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        println("cannot connect to server", err.Error())
    }

    conn, err := stomp.Connect(netConn, options...)
    if err != nil {
        println("cannot connect to server", err.Error())
    }

    sub, err := conn.Subscribe(*queueName, stomp.AckAuto)
    if err != nil {
        println("cannot subscribe to", *queueName, err.Error())
        return
    }
    close(subscribed)

    for i := 1; i <= *messageCount; i++ {
        msg := <-sub.C
        expectedText := fmt.Sprintf("Message #%d", i)
        actualText := string(msg.Body)
        fmt.Println("got message", actualText, " ", time.Now())
        if expectedText != actualText {
            println("Expected:", expectedText)
            println("Actual:", actualText)
        }
    }
    println("receiver finished")

}
```

Comment: How would using RabbitMQ help solve this?